# How to properly use the gem 'attr_encrypted' during a migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cypher, ruby-on-rails-5, attr-encrypted

I am adding the [attr_encrypted gem](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted) to an existing model.

The problem that I am having is that the data on the migration is not converting.
When I create a new record, I do see it encrypted.

My migration looks like this.

```
class AddEncryptedAttributesToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_new_fields
    rename_original_fields
    recreate_original_fields
    encrypt_data
    remove_holding_fields
  end

  def create_new_fields
    add_column :users, :encrypted_email, :string
    add_column :users, :encrypted_email_iv, :string
  end

  def rename_original_fields
    rename_column :users, :email, :o_email
  end

  def recreate_original_fields
    add_column :users, :email, :string
  end

  def encrypt_data
    User.find_each do |user|
      user.email              = user.o_email
      user.save
    end
  end

  def remove_holding_fields
    remove_column :users, :o_email, :string
  end

end
```

In my user model, I added the description keys.

```
attr_encrypted :email, key: ENV['SECRET_KEY_BASE'].scan(/../).map { |x| x.hex }.pack('C*')
```

After the migration is run, I can run my user factory, and I see the data adequately encrypted but just not in this migration.

UPDATE
I just double check
if I create a new user and then close and reopen the console, then I don't see the value of `user.email`

Thanks for the help

Comment: Not sure if it's a copy/paste error, but you're referring to the `admins` table in the `rename_original_fields` method, but `users` table everywhere else. But also: I don't think you want to add another `email` column? The attribute is handled via `encrypted_email` instead.

Comment: This is kind of a side note but there is no point in breaking up a migration into a bunch of methods. It's only supposed to be used for a short period of time and then be deleted. If you do feel the temptation to do some it should be telling your that you're doing to much in a single migration.

Comment: Also updating the existing records should be done via a rake task and not a migration. If you have a lot of records it could take a long time to run which could lead to the migration timing out and leaving the schema in a broken state.

Comment: @pat ty, yes, that was a copy-paste error.

Comment: *"but just not in this migration"* could you describe your issue in a bit more detail? Is the existing data not converted? Do you get errors? What exactly is the problem you're facing?

Comment: Breaking up migrations into many functions this way makes them very hard to read. They should be written in side the `change` method, which reads top-to-bottom.